# Is my measurement setup correct for the common mode frequency response?

Tags: bode-plot

I’m using a USB scope which can be used as also a network analyzer. For a network like a passive filter, to obtain Bode plots one input channel is set for reference the other as output. And the input signal is set and swept by a wave generator input. Settings are done via a software. The input channels are differential; for example for channel one Ch1+ and Ch1- are the inputs for a signal.

Below is the wiring for an RC low pass filter to use as a network analyzer and to obtain Bode plots:

[image]

W1 is the sweeping wave generator input; Ch1 is the reference channel; Ch2 is the output; Ground is the common ground for input channels and W1.

Now I want to obtain the common-mode response Bode plot of the following choke circuit by the same device:

[image]

Is my way of wiring correct below?:

[image]

Will I obtain common mode freq. response if I use the above measurement setup?

Second attempt:

[image]

Comment: Does the wave generator not have a ground/return/reference terminal?

Comment: It has its own ground that is shown by triangle ground symbol in my drawings.

Comment: Thats the only ground in the setup.

Comment: No. That will measure the differential voltage only.

Comment: Are you going to compute a scalar or vector result of Zcm for the choke?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Bode plots for CM only

Comment: @panicattack, there are triangle grounds at both ends of the device under test (DUT). Are you saying the wave generator is connected at both places?

Comment: @ThePhoton There is only one device which does the job. The USB device. Here is the pinout https://wiki.analog.com/university/tools/m2k/users/understanding And here is the software to use as network analyzer  https://wiki.analog.com/university/tools/m2k/scopy/networkanalyzer

Comment: Yes, but can you edit your post to make it clear how you connected it? You said it is connected where the triangle ground is shown, but there are two triangle grounds in your drawings (2 out of 3, anyway).

Comment: I didn’t connect yet but my last drawing was my plan. Is it not clear I named all the pins in drawing. Let me know I can edit whatever missing.

Comment: Oh you are right thats a bit confusing for me I guess

Comment: Yes I was planning to connect both grounds maybe wrong

Comment: How about this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmrrO.jpg ? Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I suggest.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxISMK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

CM Choke use flux addition and DM uses flux cancellation.

Ideally the DM only sees the wire resistance.  Such as a clamshell ferrites or beads around wire pair has no effect on DM impedance.

The wire balanced impedance also matters after the caps or imbalance Z.  **A High input impedance gets little or no benefit from raising impedance of CM choke alone unless shunt cap is after.**  The lower the impedance of the load, the more DM CMRR.

Comment: Thanks would it be too much if I need your help to use this drawing instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqETJ.jpg ? I need to be sure about it to relate to your diagrams symbols.

Comment: Is the location of the Y-capacitor "C1" correct?

Comment: I think C1 C2 are stray capacitances. But can you also add the Y capacitors after the choke?